# how to get the 'user' object in django

Tags: django

i want to get the user who login now ..

how to do this ..

thanks

this is my code :

```
ps=Position.objects.filter(name=User.username)
```

**updated:**

```
ps=Position.objects.filter(name=request.user.username)
```

and

```
return render_to_response(template_name, {
        "map_form": map_form,
        "map": map,
        "group": map, # @@@ this should be the only context var for the map
        "is_member": is_member,
        "ps":ps
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in the html:

```
var ps='{{ ps.name }}'
alert(ps)
```

and it does print nothing ?

why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`request.user` has the logged-in user.

Comment: `ps` is a `QuerySet`. QuerySets don't have a `name` attribute.

Comment: If you like. But why not use `.get()` in the first place?

Comment: here you can find a tutorial about Django users http://lowcoupling.com/post/71289666862/django-the-user-tutorial there is also a GitHub project you can clone and check